# Do I need to stop spark after creating sparksession using pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

So I have this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("NewSpark").getOrCreate()
```

I heard you need to stop spark once you're done but is this necessary in my case since it's just a python program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The session will be closed if the `spark` object gets destroyed or if the script exits.  So you shouldn't need to worry about "dangling connections" or anything like that.

However, if you have a bunch of non-spark work that you want to do at the end of the script, it may still be a good idea to stop the session early to avoid holding that connection open.

Note that you can use the `SparkSession` object as a context manager to automatically stop it at the end of a scope:

```
with SparkSession.builder.appName("NewSpark").getOrCreate() as spark:
    # do stuff
    # ...

# spark.stop() gets called automatically here
```